# Typescript inferring Tuple as Array Incorrectly

Tags: typescript, casting, tuples

Apologize for my English first.

I have a function like `function func(): [string, string[]]` which returns a Tuple. However, when I implement the return statement like

```
var test = ['text', ['foo', 'bar']];
return test;
```

Typescript inferred my return type as `(string | string[])[]` instead of `[string, string[]]`.

Did I missed something or should I need to cast the return object as Tuple explicitly everytime like `return <[string, string[]]>['text', ['foo', 'bar']]`. If yes then isn't it quite annoying?

Provided the full function as follow:

```
function func(): [string, string[]] {
    var test= ['text', ['foo', 'bar']];

    return test;
}
```

Error:
`Type '(string | string[])[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, string[]]': 0, 1ts(2739)`

[image]

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAKAlALkQbQM5QBOMYA5gDSIHFk4C6diA3gFCLuKECmUIhSOAORQuADyiDKQ4HDiTEggEYBDQoIYBuFgF8WQA)

Comment: 1. Please post code, not images of code. 2. Your image example is indeed different - you should have posted that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TS cannot differentiate, if you want `['text', ['foo', 'bar']]` to be an [array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) or a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) - the *expression* is the same! It will default to an array for the `test` variable type, if nothing else specified.

If you want a tuple, do one of the following:

- use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)
- give `test` an explicit tuple type

```
function func(): [string, string[]] {
    const test = ['text', ['foo', 'bar']];
    const test2 = ['text', ['foo', 'bar']] as const;
    const test3: [string, string[]] = ['text', ['foo', 'bar']];
    // return test;   // error, was inferred as array
    // return test2; // works
    return test3; // works
}
```

With `as const` you don't have to repeat your type, but you will have to annotate the function return type with `readonly` modifiers: `readonly [string, readonly [string, string]]`.